# ipad does not show up in Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I'm trying to build an Adobe Air app.  On one of my computers, I was able to connect the ipad and deploy to it.

Then I copied the *.p12 and *.mobileprovision files over to another computer that also has Flash Builder.  I made sure flash builder pointed to these files.  ITunes recognized the ipad as soon as I connected it via USB.  But when I tell flash builder to deploy to the device, flash builder isn't aware of the device.

Does anyone know how to correct this issue?

I tried these instructions here.  But still it didn't solve the problem for the second computer i'm having trouble with.  Things continue to deploy properly via the first computer.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-6caff02f136a645e895-7ffe.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-708ff844136ba66f601-7ff4

Comment: Be conform. Have you made Mobile application in flash builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem.  It was because the latest release of iTunes around Feb 2 causes issues with Flash builder.  I followed the instructions explained in this forum: https://support.muse.adobe.com/thread/1296966?start=0&tstart=0, which I'll summarize below:

..............................

The files seem correct. My guess is that there are still files left over from the old misleading versions of iTunes.

1) Un-install Apple Application support 32 bit/64 bit, Apple Mobile Device Support, Apple Software Update, and iTunes

2) Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files and delete the Apple folder

3) C:\Program Files\Common Files and delete the Apple folder

4) Download and Re-install this version of itunes: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1784?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US ( if you have it downloaded already you don't have to download again) ****Make sure when the installer starts, the installer asks you to install your files in the Program ( 86x ) folder!****

5) Restart your computer